# How to get Google Account last activity info with more precision than a simple date?

Tags: gmail, google-account, javascript

Under `Gmail page > Activity Information (low right hand corner)` page, I can see:

[image]

As per the last few rows, the information is certainly not helpful as they are accurate only to the day instead of the hour.

When an account is suspected to be compromised, where to get more useful info/audit/logs regarding a Google Account's security? Is there some Javascript code that I can run on the page itself to obtain this info?

Comment: There is a mouse over tooltip for those dates

Comment: @eckes I can't find the tooltip. Steps to reproduce? Offer and alternate answer?

Comment: Don’t have a mouse here so I can’t try it, I thought I have seen those pop ups, but maybe only in the inbox view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google offers a very detailed log for you to review:

https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity

It has a date filter and shows minute-by minute activity.